# Extract Guid in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to extract guid from below string, had no success. I tried substring to but that's not working as expected. Any idea?

class Response201 {\n Id: 6cbfc27e-2bd4-4259-b94a-fe7ddeb88ef5\n}'

Tried this :

SELECT JSON_VALUE('class Response201 {\n Id: 6cbfc27e-2bd4-4259-b94a-fe7ddeb88ef5\n}', '$.id') AS value
FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 0):

We can user `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`

> ```
> SELECT 
> REGEXP_SUBSTR ('class Response201 {\n Id: 6cbfc27e-2bd4-4259-b94a-fe7ddeb88ef5\n}',
>               '([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})') AS GUID
> FROM dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> | GUID                                 |
> | :----------------------------------- |
> | 6cbfc27e-2bd4-4259-b94a-fe7ddeb88ef5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4da2434c1f963aea6959168ecc58ae34)*